# Read/write the contents of an array of doubles to internal storage

Tags: android, kotlin

I have used sample code from developer.android.com. I was planing to change the code to see if it would accept this: `writeObject(123.456)`. I can't get it to compile even with out my added code...

```
//converted to Kotlin
val fos = FileOutputStream("t.tmp")
val oos = ObjectOutputStream(fos)

//original Java code
oos.writeInt(12345)
oos.writeObject("Today")
oos.writeObject(Date())

oos.close()

// original Java code
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("t.tmp")
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)

oos.writeInt(12345)
oos.writeObject("Today")
oos.writeObject(new Date ())

oos.close()
```

Comment: The begining code should read:  //converted to Kotlin
    val fos = FileOutputStream("t.tmp")
    val oos = ObjectOutputStream(fos), Not Original Java Code

Comment: This question belongs in the `android` tag, since it has nothing to do with Compose, I mean there's not a single compose logic in the code you provided so consider migrating the tag.

Comment: What is your goal? Simply read/write doubles in a file? If yes, you should go with `FileWriter` https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileWriter

Comment: If you cannot let it compile then what is the compile error,? On which statement?

Comment: I got it to compile by changing the first 2 line of code:                                                val fos = FileOutputStream("t.tmp")
    val oos =  ObjectOutputStream(fos)

Comment: I changed the first to lines of code:                                                                          val fos = FileOutputStream("t.tmp")
    val oos =  ObjectOutputStream(fos) and it now compile, When I run it my app crashes on the first item.

Comment: What is the first item? And which exception is not catched? Please post relevant logcat lines.

Comment: FileOutputStream expects a full path. Not only a file name like you do.

Comment: Wrapping the code -  val fos = FileOutputStream(fileName) in a try//catch gives me a file no found  message with a note that the file was read -only. The file is internal - could it be a be that I don't have permission?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the file name must be preceded by context.getFilesDir()

```
   fun WriteData(context: Context) {
        val appFilesDirectory: File = context.getFilesDir()
        val file = File(appFilesDirectory, "data.dbl")
        val fos = FileOutputStream(file)
        val oos = ObjectOutputStream(fos)
        for (i in regs.indices) {
            oos.writeObject(regs[i])
        }

        oos.close()
        var OK = ""
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        var notOK = ""
    }
}
```